# Need help creating and unknown amount of named pipes to split and sort data

Tags: c, sorting, fork, pipe, named-pipes

Okay, so I am an assignment that I am completely stuck on regarding pipes. The goal was to take in a "depth" "filename" and "attribute" from the command line. The file is a txt file which holds user information, the attribute is simply which information we want to  later sort by. The depth, however, is important because I need to create a binary tree, using forks, based on the number the user enters. With a depth of 1 I would have my main process, one internal node, and 2 leaf nodes. With a depth of two I would have my main process, one internal node that has two internal nodes as children, and they each have two leaf nodes as children... and so on.

My code currently reads in all of the information into an array of structs, creates the binary tree of the correct amount of nodes, and all of my sorting algorithms (Shell, Quick, Bubble) work.

Now, I must implement named- pipes and pass the data down to the leaf nodes for sorting. Each internal node is supposed to split the data down to it's children. Then, once the data reaches the leaf nodes they will implement a different sorting algorithm and return the results to their parent/internal. The internal nodes will take the sorted data from it's two children and merge the results. Eventually, the data will be merged all the way back to the anchor node.

My problem is that I cannot wrap my mind around pipes at all. I do not know how to keep track of them or initialize them at the right time. I thought about finding out how many leaf nodes should be produced by the depth given and splitting the data evenly that way, then just making an if statement to run the correct sorter on each part of the data, but that would not be solving the correct problem. Can anyone at all help me implement this, or at least something to start with?

the creation of the tree looks like this

```
void forkTree(int size){
if(size == 0){
    return;
}
int left = fork();
if(left != 0){
    int right = fork();
        if(right == 0){
            sleep(1);
            forkTree(size-1);
        }
}
else{
    sleep(1);
    forkTree(size-1);
}
```

and it is invoked like this

```
if(depth>0){
//initial fork
int anchor = fork();
//make binary tree only in child process
if(anchor==0){
    forkTree(depth);
}
```

Comment: Named pipes are like files. create one with mkfifo, and you can use the read(2) and write(2) calls to write to them. What specifically do you not understand? their creation or their use?

Comment: @WoodrowDouglass  Well, at first I did not realize that in recursively making these pipes they could have the same name in different processes. I just can't keep track who is getting and sending what.

Comment: Are you required to use named pipes? Seems more simple to do without?

Comment: If you're not required to use named pipe, create unnamed pipes with the pipe() system call. It's better since it doesn't clog up the file system with named pipes. If you still need it you can generate names based on getpid() since each of your child processes have their own PID. Anyway, let us know if named pipes are required!

Answer (score 0):

Look at documentation about [`pipe`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe). Each pipe has two ends, one for read a and one for write. You need two of them per each child when you want write data to the child and then read result. If you have a binary tree you have two children in each node. So it is four pipes and eight file handles where you close half of them on both parent's and children's side. In parent node, you close the reading end of the pipe for writing to the child and the writing end of the pipe for reading from the child. In the child, you do the opposite. You can look at the example in  the manual page and adapt for you task. I recommend you to separate code for forking of one child into the separate function. You can even write data to the child in this function and return only reading end of the pipe. Then read from both pipes from both children. Don't forget `wait` for both children to reap zombies.

There is example from the manual page:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int pipefd[2];
    pid_t cpid;
    char buf;
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <string>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (pipe(pipefd) == -1) {
        perror("pipe");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    cpid = fork();
    if (cpid == -1) {
        perror("fork");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (cpid == 0) {    /* Child reads from pipe */
        close(pipefd[1]);          /* Close unused write end */

        while (read(pipefd[0], &buf, 1) > 0)
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, &buf, 1);

        write(STDOUT_FILENO, "\n", 1);
        close(pipefd[0]);
        _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

    } else {            /* Parent writes argv[1] to pipe */
        close(pipefd[0]);          /* Close unused read end */
        write(pipefd[1], argv[1], strlen(argv[1]));
        close(pipefd[1]);          /* Reader will see EOF */
        wait(NULL);                /* Wait for child */
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
}
```